# How to detect if a icecast / shoutcast stream exists or not?

Tags: php, audio, audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

There are 5 streams on a website. I need to detect if these streams exist. If not, there are some audio files to play instead.

I'm using html5 to play the stream and stream urls look like this :

http://locus.creacast.com:9001/StBaume_grotte.ogg

I've tried different things but it doesn't seem to work. Streams are never detected.

Solution 1 :
Here, i simply tried to check if file exists.

```
if (file_exists($stream_1)) {
             $debug_output_stream_1 = "Le fichier $stream_1 existe.";
             $erreur_404_Stream_1 = true;  
        } else {
             $debug_output_stream_1 =  "Le fichier $stream_1 n'existe pas.";
             $erreur_404_Stream_1 = false;  
        }
```

Solutions 2 :
I try to detect a 404 error

```
 $file_headers_1 = @get_headers($stream_1);
        if($file_headers_1[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
            $debug_output_stream_1 = "StBaume_sommet.ogg : L'URL n'existe pas.";
            $erreur_404_Stream_1 = true;  
        }
        else {
            $debug_output_stream_1 = "StBaume_sommet.ogg : L'URL existe.";
            $erreur_404_Stream_1 = false;
        }
```

Do you know how to check if streams exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking the entire status line, including the HTTP version `HTTP/1.1`.  Most servers return `HTTP/1.0`.  You need to check the status code only.

```
if (strpos($file_headers_1[0], '200 OK') === false) {
    // error occurred
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Do you know why it takes a very long time to check if my streams exist, but if i check a url like "http://stackoverflow.com", the check is very quick. Is it a server issue ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel It can have many causes. Network, server (mis)configuration and many others. Try to take it step by step and  check each possible cause until you find the problem.

Comment: Best to check just the status code number, and ignore the message with it.